# Data structure for large set of stepwise/incremental data and method to store it

Tags: database, data-structures

I don't know if I don't know the correct terms or if what I'm looking for simply isn't a common structure, so please bear with me as I try to describe what I am looking for.

Right now I have a sorted set. It changes over time with simple modifications. A (k,v) pair is inserted, deleted, or the value of a specific key may change.

No actions are or ever will be executed on more than a single key.

What I need is a way to store each incremental version of the data set and have it be mapped to a point in time. I will need to access any portion of it quickly and be able to generate the exact sorted set that existed at that time, and how it changed over the time period.

It is not feasible to store the actual sorted sets after each mutation themselves as it is about 10kb of data and will have approximately 2-3 mutations per second on average. This is a personal project so writing 2.5 gigabytes of data per set (times 10-20 sets) per day is cost prohibitive.

**Now I have come up with a solution - and here lies my question, does the solution I've come up with have a term? Is there a better way to do it?**

If I have an initial dataset `Orders`, the next iteration of data could be written as `Orders + (K,V)` then instead of storing the entire set twice, I simply store the actual set once, and then the second time it is stored as a reference + the mutation.

Then if I wanted to access Orders[n] I would iterative Orders[0] -> Order[n] applying the mutation and I would generate the set as it existed in time.

There is a big problem with this however. I need to be able to quickly access any range of data - roughly 250,000 iterations per day * months or years - so it is not practical to calculate the set from 0 -> n when n is large. The obvious solution here is to at some interval cache the resulting set and instead of a given data point recursively being calculated all the way back to Orders[0] it would only need to calculate back to `Orders[1,500,000]` to find the set which existed at `Orders[1,500,100]`.

If I decided this was a good way to structure the data, how often should I cache results?

Does something like this exist? In my research a lot of sources said to use linked lists or binary trees. I don't need a tree as my data is 100% continuous, not branching. So if I used a linked list my confusion lies in actually storing the data. And this is where I am completely stuck. What would be the best database & database schema to store this? (could use any system at this point, though having a node.js wrapper would be ideal as that is what is serving the data to the front-end) Or would writing binary data work better?

Even something as simple as an actual term for what I'm looking for or an alternative data structure to research would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an excellent use case for a persistent binary search tree. A persistent data structure is one where after performing an operation on the structure, you get back two structures - the one before the change and the one after the change. Crucially, the internal representations of the two structures share memory, so if you have a 10KB collection, it takes much less than 20KB to store the before and after snapshots.

Since you want a key/value store, a persistent binary search tree might be your best bet. Like a normal BST, all operations run in O(log n) time. You can then store an array of all the snapshots, giving you O(1) access to any time slice you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! While the data structure itself is relatively simple to implement, I'm not sure what the best way to actually store the data for retrieval is. I won't be able to load it all into RAM either. Do you have any suggestions for how to go about actually implementing it in terms of persistent storage not simply remaining in RAM?

Comment: With a persistent BST, each update uses roughly log n new memory, which is really not very much. You'd have to have billions of updates for this to be a problem. Is that the case?

Comment: No it isn't, ~100 million updates / year. Regardless I'm not sure what I was thinking, it should fit into memory fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data structures you are talking about are typically known as "persistent data structures" or sometimes "immutable data structures."